# Static Content Security

Tags: html, cloud-computing, storage

I have some static content HTML in a cloud storage space/ CDN.
How can I serve this only to authenticated users?
I am planning to use these static content on   edx platforms.
How can I securely deliver my static content within OpenEdx.
Is there anyway to allow request only from my edx server?
Also is there any  other way to achieve this?

Comment: The HTML is just data, which by itself has no limits on where it gets send to. Any such restrictions need thus be implemented at the level of the cloud storage / CDN.  There is neither a single provider for this nor is there are generic set of capabilities common to all providers. On top of this the content is likely not requested from your edx server but just embedded there - and actually requested by the client, so restricting access to the edx server is not what you actually want.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich is there any way an API can be implemented in the middle of a request?

Comment: What you would need is some kind of authenticated access integrated with OpenEdx authentication. If OpenEdx and whatever platform you use for hosting the content both support the same authentication provider (like login with Google, Facebook, ...) you might restrict the content for both with some efforts. But I don't see any real integration or support within OpenEdx to make such a setup easy.